# Generics fail in stream operation

Tags: java, generics, stream

could someone explain me why following code works and the stream version does not?

**Normal version:**

```java
public static <T> String generateUpdateStatement(
            final PersistableBusinessObject<T> persistableBusinessObject, final MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters) {

        Map<T, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(T pf: persistableBusinessObject.getUpdatableFieldNames()){
            map.put(pf, persistableBusinessObject.get(pf));
        }

        return 'some return value'
    }
```

**Stream version:**

```java
public static <T> String generateUpdateStatement(
            final PersistableBusinessObject<T> persistableBusinessObject, final MapSqlParameterSource namedParameters) {

        Map<T, Object> updatedFields = persistableBusinessObject.getUpdatableFieldNames()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f, persistableBusinessObject::get));

        return 'some return value'
    }
```

I am getting following error when using stream: can not find symbol class T
[image]

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.toMap((T f) -> f, f -> persistableBusinessObject.get(f)));`

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sotirios, let me try. Turing85, I see your point, let me write the error than.

Comment: Yes, but I am getting this error in runtime, compiler does not complain about it.

Comment: Generics are getting thrown out of the window after compilation.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, let me correct that, but the situation is the same

Comment: I have tried this: `.collect(Collectors.toMap((T f) -> f, f -> persistableBusinessObject.get(f)));` but it does not work either.

Comment: Is the name of your class really `idea.debugger.rt.GeneratedEvaluationClass` or do you have one or more expressions entered into the debugger for runtime evaluation?

Comment: I have entered it into debugger for runtime evaluation.